# NamedPipeServer Max Connection

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

Hi
Whats the maximum number of concurrent connection to a namedpipe server on the same machine (client and server on same machine) or whats the number of this limitation for different machines

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of instances that can be created for this pipe. The first instance of the pipe can specify this value; the same number must be specified for other instances of the pipe. Acceptable values are in the range 1 through PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES (255).

If this parameter is PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, the number of pipe instances that can be created is limited only by the availability of system resources. If nMaxInstances is greater than PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, the return value is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and GetLastError returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

Comment: So if i want to use namedpipe in multithreaded application there would be 255 maximum concurrent connection on the same machine ??

Comment: Ehsan: No, he's saying that if you pass 255 for the limit, then there is no limit.